# Sample Size Calculation-Theory

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample

thanks for all the knowledge, have learned a lot.

I am preparing for the sample size calculation block in my master program and I have a question regarding the theory of it all. As a medical doctor I have to cover sometimes many holes in mathematical knowledge but I am trying.

Primarily, I have been trying to understand why in the following picture taken from Kieser, Fallzahlberechnung in der medizinischen Forschung: Eine Einführung für Mediziner und Biostatistiker (essentials), the distance between $z_1-a/2$ and the non centrality parameter $λ z_1-β$ is, if we consider that $z_1-a/2$ constitutes the zcritical.

[image: Sample Size Calculation]

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.